# Unexpected pattern matching behaviour using a trait with parameterized types

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, traits, type-erasure

I'm seeing the following behaviour in scala 2.12.9:

```
case class A()
case class B()

trait X {
  type T

  def handle: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case in: T =>
      println(s"is a T, $in")
    case m =>
      print(s"not a T, $m")
  }

}

class X1 extends X {
  override type T = A
}


object Cast extends App {
  val x1 = new X1()
  x1.handle(B())
}
```

The output is *is a T, B()*. I expected it to be "not a T", since I have overriden the type parameter of X to A. What am I missing?

**Update:**
I wasn't aware that type members (not just type parameters) are also affected by type erasure. Thank you all! @DmytroMitin's answer workarounds work perfectly.

Comment: I am surprised that `in: T` works, and it is probably because at that point `T` is treated as an **Any** so everything will match. In general, this design feels unsafe. What exactly do you want to solve here? what is the meta-prioblem? If you are open to suggestions we could try to provide a safer design.

Comment: Type members and type parameters are erased at runtime, so you can't check if something is an instance of `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of type erasure.

During compilation there is a warning

```
abstract type pattern X.this.T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

Try

```
import shapeless.TypeCase

trait X {
  type T

  val OfTypeT: TypeCase[T] // abstract val, not def

  def handle: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case OfTypeT(in) =>
      println(s"is a T, $in")
    case m =>
      print(s"not a T, $m")
  }    
}

class X1 extends X {
  override type T = A
  override val OfTypeT = TypeCase[A]
}

val x1 = new X1()
x1.handle(B()) // not a T, B()
```

See *Ways to pattern match generic types in Scala* https://gist.github.com/jkpl/5279ee05cca8cc1ec452fc26ace5b68b (another copy of a blog post: http://web.archive.org/web/20171013214913/http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/ways-to-pattern-match-generic-types-in-scala)

If `T` were a type parameter rather than type member we could use a context bound instead of overriding

```
import shapeless.{TypeCase, Typeable}

abstract class X[T: Typeable] {
  private val OfTypeT = TypeCase[T]

  def handle: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case OfTypeT(in) =>
      println(s"is a T, $in")
    case m =>
      print(s"not a T, $m")
  }
}

class X1 extends X[A]

val x1 = new X1()
x1.handle(B()) // not a T, B()
```

Or we could use `TypeTag`

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf, Type}

def getType[T: TypeTag](t: T): Type = typeOf[T]

abstract class X[T: TypeTag] {
  def handle: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case in if typeOf[T] =:= getType(in) =>
      println(s"is a T, $in")
    case m =>
      print(s"not a T, $m")
  }
}

class X1 extends X[A]

val x1 = new X1()
x1.handle(B()) // not a T, B()
```

or `ClassTag`

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

abstract class X[T: ClassTag] {
  def handle: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case in: T =>
      println(s"is a T, $in")
    case m =>
      print(s"not a T, $m")
  }
}

class X1 extends X[A]

val x1 = new X1()
x1.handle(B()) // not a T, B()
```